# How to "walk" inside two arrays using the same *ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript

Basically I have two arrays, and I would like to store their values at the same time using a `*ngFor`, I did something like this just to show what I would expect:

```
<div formArrayName="alternativeFields" *ngFor="let field of alternativeFields.controls; let i = index">
            <mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="fullSize">
              <mat-label>Titulo</mat-label>
              <input [formControlName]="i" type="text" matInput id="field_{{i}}" autocomplete="off"
                placeholder="Titulo">
            </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    
     <div formArrayName="alternativeFieldsValues" *ngFor="let value of alternativeFieldsValues.controls; let i = index">
              <mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="fullSize">
                  <mat-label>Conteúdo</mat-label>
                  <input [formControlName]="i" type="text" matInput id="value_{{i}}" autocomplete="off"
                    placeholder="Conteúdo deste campo">
              </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

Also have that function that puts the Inputs into the HTML:

```
addAlternativeField() {
        this.alternativeFields.push(this.fbuilder.control(''));
        this.alternativeFieldsValues.push(this.fbuilder.control(''));
      }
```

The obvius problem is that after the first push the fields are not going to be as I would like(TITLE/VALUE ; TITLE/VALUE):

[image: 1º Execution]

At the second execution that's what I get:

[image: 2º Execution]

I would like to know how to keep that desired format(TITULO/CONTEUDO), without that problem above.
I don't think it's very hard, but I don't know if I can do it In a simple way using the *ngFor

I also tried to do something like this:

```
<div formArrayName="alternativeFields" *ngFor="let field of alternativeFields.controls; let i = index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="fullSize">
            <mat-label>Titulo</mat-label>
            <input formControlName="alternativeFields" type="text" matInput autocomplete="off"
              placeholder="Titulo">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="fullSize">
            <mat-label>Conteúdo</mat-label>
            <input formControlName="alternativeFieldsValues" type="text" matInput autocomplete="off"
              placeholder="Conteúdo deste campo">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
```

But I got that error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'alternativeFields -> 0 -> alternativeFields'
    at _throwError (forms.js:2144)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2052)
    at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5281)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:5882)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5803)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22095)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23363)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23325)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23959)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23919)
```

It says these are not defined at the form, but they actually are:

```
this.form = this.fbuilder.group({
      index: [''],
      id: [''],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      value: ['', Validators.required],
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: [''],
      alternativeFields: this.fbuilder.array([]),
      alternativeFieldsValues: this.fbuilder.array([])
    });
```

Some tips?

## EDIT:

I have these methods aswell:

```
get alternativeFields() {
    return this.form.get('alternativeFields') as FormArray;
  }

  get alternativeFieldsValues() { 
    return this.form.get('alternativeFieldsValues') as FormArray;
  }
  
  addAlternativeField() {
    this.alternativeFields.push(this.fbuilder.control(''));
  }

  removeAlternativeField(index: any) {
    this.alternativeFields.removeAt(index);
  }

  get f() { return this.form.controls; }
```

Comment: Your array doesn't show any element at this point. When do you add elements to the alternative Arrays?

Comment: everytime I push a "addAlternativeField" it adds the Input at the HTML, so if I write any content at it, it gets the values inside the Array

Comment: I have this button:

 <button type="button" (click)="addAlternativeField()" mat-flat-button color="primary">
            Add Extra Fields
          </button>

Comment: Please create a example in https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Comment: I never used stackblitz, but it's something like this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qc5z6b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your mistake is having 2 arrays of controls instead of one array of groups:

```
alternativeFieldsAndValues: this.fbuilder.array([]),
```

and then:

```
 get alternativeFieldsAndValues() {
   return this.form.get('alternativeFieldsAndValues') as FormArray;
 }

  addAlternativeFieldAndValue() {
    this.alternativeFieldsAndValues.push(this.fbuilder.group({
      titulo: '',
      conteudo: ''
    }));
  }

  removeAlternativeFieldAndValue(index: any) {
    this.alternativeFieldsAndValues.removeAt(index);
  }
```

make sure to refactor all names properly then do this:

```
 <div formArrayName="alternativeFieldsAndValues" *ngFor="let field of alternativeFieldsAndValues.controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="fullSize">
        <mat-label>Titulo</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="titulo" type="text" matInput autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="Titulo">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="fullSize">
        <mat-label>Conteúdo</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="conteudo" type="text" matInput autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="Conteúdo deste campo">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
```

that being said, you could accomplish exactly what you asked like this:

```
   <div *ngFor="let field of alternativeFields.controls; let i = index">
      <mat-form-field formArrayName="alternativeFields" appearance="standard" class="fullSize">
        <mat-label>Titulo</mat-label>
        <input [formControlName]="i" type="text" matInput autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="Titulo">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field formArrayName="alternativeFieldsValues" appearance="standard" class="fullSize">
        <mat-label>Conteúdo</mat-label>
        <input [formControlName]="i" type="text" matInput autocomplete="off"
          placeholder="Conteúdo deste campo">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

but this does require the two lists are ALWAYS of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

Matheus, a formArray can be a FormArray of FormControls or a FormArrays of FormGroup (*)

```
    form=new FormGroup({
       arrayOfControls=new FormArray([])
    })
    pushArrayOfControls()
    {
       this.form.get('arrayOfControls').push(new FormControl())
    }
    //or using FormBuilder
  this.form = this.fb.group(
      {
        arrayOfControls: this.fb.array([])
      }
  )
  pushArrayOfControls() {
    (this.form.get('arrayOfControls') as FormArray).push(
      this.fb.control('')
    )
  }
```

A formArray of FormGroup:

```
form=new FormGroup({
   arrayOfFormGroup=new FormArray([])
})
pushArrayOfFormGroup()
{
   this.form.get('arrayOfControls').push(
     new FormGroup({
         prop1:new FormControl()
         prop2:new FormControl()
     }))
}
//or using FormBuilder
form=this.fb.group({
   arrayOfFormGroup=this.fb.array([])
})
pushArrayOfFormGroup()
{
   this.form.get('arrayOfControls').push(this.fb.group({
      prop1:'',
      prop2:''
   })
}
```

One store an array of values ['a','b','c'], the other store an array of object [{prop1:'a',prop2:'aa'},{prop1:'a',prop2:'aa'}]

To manage it's use different ways. The clasic for a FormArray of controls is

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="arrayOfControls">
    <div *ngFor="let control of form.get('arrayOfControls').controls;let i=index">
      <!---use [formControlName]="i"-->
      <input [formControlName]="i"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But remember, our formArray is a formArray of control, so we can do something like

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="arrayOfControls">
    <div *ngFor="let control of form.get('arrayOfControls').controls;">
      <!---use [formControl]="control", the variable of the *ngFor-->
      <input [formControl]="control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And we can make something so "bizarro" like

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="arrayOfControls">
    <div *ngFor="let control of form.get('arrayOfControls').controls;let i=index">
      <input [formControl]="form.get('arrayOfControls').at(i)"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A formArray of formGroup, we can the way clasic

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="arrayOfFormGroup">
    <!--see that we use [formGroupName]-->
    <div *ngFor="let control of form.get('arrayOfFormGroup').controls;
           let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="prop1"/>
      <input formControlName="prop2"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Well, nobody say that we can not do, remember that is a formArray of controls, so, for.get('arrayOfGroup').controls is a FormGroup

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="arrayOfControls">
     <!--here I used "formGroup"-->
    <div *ngFor="let group of form.get('arrayOfControls').controls"
        [formGroup]="group">
      <input formControlName="prop1"/>
      <input formControlName="prop2"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

even something so "bizarro"

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="arrayOfControls">
    <div *ngFor="let group of form.get('arrayOfControls').controls;let i=index" >
       <!--I used directily [formControl]-->
      <input [formControl]="form.get('arrayOfControls').at(i).get('prop1')"/>
      <input [formControl]="form.get('arrayOfControls').at(i).get('prop2')"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Well, now, the question is: What do you want? a formArray of FormGroup or an formArray of FormControls, what way of referered to the FormControls do you wants, using formControl, using formControlName, using formGroup?

NOTE: it's usefull use a getter to referered to our formArray

```
get myArray()
{
    return this.form.get('arrayOfControls') as FormArray
}
```

and replace in the .html this "ugly" form.get(....)

(*)Really a FormArray don't need create into a formGroup, they "lives" outside

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is here:

```
addAlternativeField() {
        this.alternativeFields.push(this.fbuilder.control(''));
        this.alternativeFieldsValues.push(this.fbuilder.control(''));
      }
```

You are patching the arrays in direct reference to this. Isn't it supposed to be

```
this.form.get('alternativeFields').push(this.fbuilder.control(''))
```

Or do you have an additional getter?

Comment: i'll edit my awnser, maybe it is what you are talking about

Comment: even doing this, I still get erros:
 Cannot find control with path: 'alternativeFields -> 0 -> alternativeFields'
  Cannot find control with path: 'alternativeFields -> 0 -> alternativeFieldsValues'