# Can't Get value from input using FormArrayName using FormBuilder

Tags: angular

When trying to get value from the input field using formArrayName it does not return any value but shows a null.
In my console, I am getting value from client name but not for secrets.
I want the value returned to be an array with only 1 value ie ["1"]. 
Please HELP! I am new to angular.

form.component.ts

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Client Name</mat-label>
      <input type="text" matInput formControlName="clientName">
      </mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Secrets</mat-label>
        <input formArrayName="secrets" matInput>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
form.ts file
    ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      clientName: ['', Validators.required],
      secrets : this.formBuilder.array([]),
      });
  }

onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.registerForm.value);
    }
```

```
  Expected output in the console
    clientName: "Value typed in input",
    secrets: ["Value typed in input"] 
    in jSON
    {
        "clientName": "test client",
        "secrets": ["secret"]
    }
```

Comment: you has a FormArray of FromControls, check the sintax correct (is NOT <input formArrayName="secrets">, you need defined a div with formArrayName and, inside [formGroupNAme]="secrest". See de oficcials doc or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271263/how-to-walk-inside-two-arrays-using-the-same-ngfor/57279838#57279838

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your expected output is:

```ts
{
  "clientName": "test client",
  "secrets": ["secret"]
}
```

You have correctly added a formarray, but you also need to add a form control inside that array. It, like any array, will have the formcontrolname `0` (index), as there is only one item in the array. So build your form as such:

```ts
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  clientName: ['', Validators.required],
  secrets: this.formBuilder.array([
    this.formBuilder.control('') // add a control
  ]),
});
```

Then in your template, like mentioned in comment, you should not mark the formarray as the input, but instead use `formControlName="0"`. The formarray should be marked on for example a div, or on the `mat-form-field`, like so:

```html
<mat-form-field formArrayName="secrets">
  <mat-label>Secrets</mat-label>
  <input formControlName="0" matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

Now you will get the desired format. **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9k5qp?file=app/input-overview-example.ts)**

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Check this [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ezf8br)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder,Validators,FormGroup ,FormArray} from '@angular/forms';
// import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder;
  registerForm;
  items;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){

  this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      clientName: ['', Validators.required],
      secrets : [this.createItem()],
      });

       console.log(this.registerForm.value);
}

createItem() {
  return this.fb.group({
    name: 'hello ',
    description: 'thiese',
    price: 'data'
  });
}
addItem(): void {
  this.items = this.registerForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  this.items.push(this.createItem());
}

}
```