# Angular Reactive Forms items not generating

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm having an angular app with a form and I'm going to use Reactive forms there. In that form there's a dropdown (Items are loading from the API). If user clicks a dropdown item , it generates a table with two fields (Inputs and label). Number of input items are generated dynamically.

Ex: If user clicks the first item of the dropdown , may be 5 input fields and labels will generate. If user clicks the second item of the dropdown , may be 2 input fields and labels will generate. This is what I tried

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    tableInputs: this.formBuilder.array([])
  })

}
```

This is the dropdown change function (getting values from API)

```
dropdownChanged(){
const control = <FormArray>this.orderForm.controls['tableInputs'];
this.apiService.listColumnData(this.selectedTable).subscribe(result=>{

  this.columns = result['data'].columns;
  control.push(new FormControl(this.columns))
});  }
```

this is how 'this.columns look like (getting from API)

```
[{0: display_name: "sales name" , id: 17, name: "sales_name",}]
```

This is how I try to render the items in view.

```
<form>
<div [formGroup]="orderForm">
<div formArrayName="tableInputs">

  <div *ngFor="let item of orderForm.controls.name; let i=index"  >

      <input formControlName="tableInputs">

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm new to Angular Reactive forms. I wasn't able to render the items. Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the response, push **formgroups** to your formarray, not single formcontrol. Also, like mentioned in other answer, clear the formarray in between. If you are using angular 8, you can use `clear()`, else loop through the formarray for example with a `while` loop.

I have made a getter for the formarray, looks cleaner in my opinion:

```ts
get tableInputs() {
  return <FormArray>this.orderForm.get('tableInputs');
}
```

Then build the form like you have and modify the `dropdownChanged()` function to:

```ts
dropdownChanged() {
  this.apiService.listColumnData(this.selectedTable).subscribe(result => {
    // clear previous formarray
    this.tableInputs.clear();
    // push new groups to formarray
    result.forEach(x => this.tableInputs.push(this.formBuilder.group(x)));
  });
}
```

If you need to add validation, you can just destruct it as follows:

```ts
  result.forEach(x => this.tableInputs.push(this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [x.id, Validators.required]
    // ....
  })));
```

Then iterate the formarray in your template and show your fields:

```html
<form [formGroup]="orderForm">
  <div formArrayName="tableInputs">
    <div *ngFor="let item of tableInputs.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="id">
      <input formControlName="display_name">
      <input formControlName="name">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Brother, have a small issue. Instead of showing item names inside input fields , I need to generate blank input fields. So     <input type="text" id="{{i}}" > correct? also I want to show the display name as label  <label>{{item.display_name}}</label> but it's not working. also validations are not showing

Comment: you need to use `item.get('display_name').value` to show the label. I'm not really understanding what the empty inputs are for. If you want some input included, you need to add that to the formgroup inside the formarray. Also... what does "validations do not show" mean, we are not seeing any validation in your question. Please create a stackblitz, and I'm happy to take a look :)

Comment: Dear brother, I created a stackblitz with a demo data (No APIs)https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wsbsvy . Just select one from dropdown.. Then you can see a label and an input. In that input I want only to show the input field. Not the id name. Also when user clicks Save and if the input field is empty I need to show the validation. Please help

Comment: yes okay, thanks for the demo. But what should the input field be for? I assume it should be a form control? You have marked it as id, but if you don't want it to be the id, why have you marked it as so?

Comment: For the input field, I want to show a blank input field. BTW, can you please help me with the validation?

Comment: Well, I added a form control in your formgroup, it's named `myInput`, change it to whatever you want it to have as a name. Validations can be shown in iteration with `item.hasError('validation name here', 'form control name here')`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzcbwn?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, a `FormArray` expects an array of `FormControls`. When you handle the response from the api you only add one control (which would result in a second item when another option in the dropdown is selected and so on).
Instead you should iterate over the received data (`this.columns.forEach(...)`).

Furthermore you can't just pass your data to a FormControl to create new ones.
I'd recommend creating a function `addFormControl(singleColumn)` as follows:

```
const tableInputs = this.orderForm.get("tableInputs") as FormArray;
tableInputs.push(this.formBuilder.group({
    display_name: singleColumn.display_name,
    name: singleColumn.name
}));
```

Also you probably want to remove the old items in the `FormArray` in case the api is called several times. Something like this should do the trick:

```
clearArray() {
    const tableInputs = this.orderForm.get("tableInputs") as FormArray;
    tableInputs = this.formBuilder.array([]);
}
```

Comment: @coderaizer, you forget [formGroupName]="i" in your div *ngFor. Sometimes ago I make a post about formArray in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271263/how-to-walk-inside-two-arrays-using-the-same-ngfor/57279838#57279838