# formarray adding row same value angular

Tags: angular, formarray

Once I added a row to `FormArray`, why it has a same object displayed.

[image]

> .HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="Form">
<div formArrayName="ItemRec">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>FORM</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let ItemRec of ItemRec.controls; let i = index;" 
[formGroupName]="i">
<td (click)="removeRow(i)" style="width:100px" align="center">
<i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i></td>
<td>
<input style="width:200px" class="form-control"
formControlName="dr" ngModel={{transactionCode}}>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

> .TS

```
this.Form = this.fb.group({
    Id:['0'],
    ItemRec: this.fb.array([this.CreateItemRec()])
  })
 }  


  CreateItemRec(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      id:[0],
      dr: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    })
}

 get ItemRec(): FormArray {
  return <FormArray>this.Form.get('ItemRec') as 
  FormArray
 }


addRow(): void {
  this.ItemRec?.push(this.CreateItemRec());
```

Comment: Because `ngModel={{transactionCode}}`, so it sets the `transactionCode` value to each form control. Meanwhile, not suggest to use form control with ngModel at the same time.

Comment: so what control should be using

Comment: Remove `ngModel={{transactionCode}}`. Since you are using reactive form, then you should get/set value from form control/form group/form array, but not using ngModel.

Comment: can you give me some example.

Comment: **remove** ngModel and use, after addRow: `this.ItemsRec.at(controls.length-1).patchValue(ItemRec.at(ItemRect.value[controls.length-2]))`

Comment: got a error

cannot find name 'controls'
cannot find name 'ItemRec', Did you mean the intance member 'this.ItemRec'?
cannot find name 'ItemRect'
cannot find name 'controls'

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<tr *ngFor="let ItemRec of ItemRec.controls; let i = index">
  <td (click)="removeRow(i)" style="width: 100px" align="center">
    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input
      style="width: 200px"
      class="form-control"
      [formGroupName]="i"
    />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I simply removed the `ngModel={{transactionCode}}` and moved the `[formGroupName]="i"` to the input

Reference:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms

Comment: get transactionCode() {
      return this.micro.transactionCode;
   } is what i wanted to display

Comment: Please create a code snippet so that we can see and troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

You has a FormArray of FormGroup -really if only has one property you should use a FormArray of FormControl, see, e.g. [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271263/how-to-walk-inside-two-arrays-using-the-same-ngfor/57279838#57279838), or this [great entry blog](https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a) to understand the diference-

As always you use a FormArray, you should use a "getter"

```
get ItemRec()
{
   return this.myForm.get('formArray') as FormArray
}
```

And if you have a FormArray of formGroup you can use a function that return a formGroup

```
createFormGroup(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {dr:null,other_property:null,...}
   return new FormGroup({
       dr:new FormControl(data.dr),
       other_property:new FormControl(data.other_property),
       ...
   })
}
```

Now you can use a function

```
add()
{
   //get the value
   const value=this.ItemRec.at(this.itemRec.controls.length-1).value;
   //simply push a new FormGroup
   this.ItemRec.push(this.createFormGroup(value)
}
```

If you use a FormArray of FormGroup is unnecesary to have a function that return the formGroup, you can simply

```
add()
{
   //get the value
   const value=this.ItemRec.at(this.itemRec.controls.length-1).value;
   //simply push a new FormGroup
   this.ItemRec.push(new FormControl(value))
}
```

NOTE: **never** use in the same tag formGroupName and ngModel. One is about ReactiveForms and another one about Template driven Form

NOTE2: the variable in your loop should be different that the FormArray, e.g.

```
<!--the variable to iterate should be different
    than the FormArray-->
<tr *ngFor="let group of ItemRec.controls;....>
```

Comment: If you has a FormControl (inside a FormGroup or inside a FormArray), the "value" or the formControl is two-way-bining in a input: when you change the input, the value change and the input show the value of the formControl. This is the reason not use [value] or [checked] or [NgModel]. Has you check the links?